# Querying a Record using concatenated Lastname & Firstname in the listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have populated my listbox with the Lastname and Firstname of users.

It was a success...However, my objective is that upon clicking a name in the text box the corresponding information must be shown in the appropriate text box. i.e. Lastname, Firstname, ID number.

Now every time I clicked a name in the list box it doesn't show anything except the first record in the database.

Here is the code I used to populate the list box:

```
Private Sub Getnames()
    'Clear ListBox
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    'Query User Names
    SQL.ExecQuery("Select * from dbo.userdb order by Lastname, Firstname")

    ' If Records are Found, Add them to List Box
    If SQL.Recordcount > 0 Then
        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            ListBox1.Items.Add(r("LastName") & "," & r("Firstname"))
        Next

        ' Set The Listbox to the First Record
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

    ElseIf SQL.Exception <> "" Then

        ' Report Error
        MsgBox(SQL.Exception)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code I am using to locate the record:

```
Private Sub GetUserDetails(ByVal Username As String)
    ' Add a Search Parameter
    SQL.AddParam("@Username", Username)

    'Run Query
    SQL.ExecQuery("Select * From dbo.userdb where (Lastname & ", " & Firstname) Like *@username*")

    'If Username is found, Send Name to Text Box
    If SQL.Recordcount > 0 Then
        TxtEmpID.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("EmpID")
        TxtFirstName.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Firstname")
        TxtLastName.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Lastname")
        CmbDept.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Department")
        CmbEmpStat.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("EmpStat")
        TxtContact.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(7)
        TxtEmail.Text = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("email")
    End If
End Sub
```

Every time I clicked the concatenated Lastname, Firstname my code doesn't show anything except the first record in the database.

Please help guys...and thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you add which database server you are using, please? The syntax in the Sql statement may be dependant on that.

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit difficult to know where to begin here. I'd probably start by throwing it all away and following this (very old now) walk through if you're set on using datasets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms171884%28v%3dvs.100%29 - there's a huge amount of time that using data binding can save you here

Comment: I can see three significant issues in your code that will impact your process. 1. When you populate the listbox you are using `r("LastName") & "," & r("Firstname")` and when you concatenate your string in the Sql you are using `(Lastname & ", " & Firstname)` - Note, there is no space added between the parts of the name in the Sql statement.

Comment: 2. When you search the database you are not looking for Exceptions on the return, just assuming there will be a valid return. As such (and depending on the internal mechanics your custom Sql class) you are looking at results from the previous query and then, only the first row.

Comment: 3. I think your Sql query `Select * From dbo.userdb where (Lastname & ", " & Firstname) Like *@username*"` is producing an error described as `Incorrect syntax near '*'`. I think your Sql query should be something like `...Like '%' + @username + '%'"` if you want to do a search.

Comment: Hi JayV, Thank you very much for your time in answering my Question...However, I tried your suggestion but It doesn't work either. Do you have any other way or code to accomplish this task. By the way I'm using MS SQL Express. Thanks again JayV. Hope to hear from you again soon...